# oracle : query output not formatted

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
SQL> SELECT TR_NAME,TR_VALUE FROM TBL;

TR_NAME
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TR_VALUE
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MN2
1

LAST_TS
1374114001657

MN1
100
```

Result of the query is not formatted. I cannot connect oracle sql developer.

How to make it readable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are using SQL*Plus

```
column tr_name format a30
column tr_value format a30
```

assuming that 30 characters is enough to display the data in both columns and that your line width is at least 60 characters.